# How should you handle players forgetting information as opposed to their characters?

Tags: gm-techniques

I'll start with the actual scenario that occurred in our last session.  Our party,  of which I am one of the PC's came across a nasty trapped/warded dirt wall.  We figured out that the trap was only triggered by contact with metal and resulted I in utterly destroying the metal. After some discussion,  we decided that we would just have to spend the time digging through it with our bare hands to avoid setting off the trap. 
Now,  as a player,  it slipped my mind I was wearing rings made out of metal. Kaboom,  and a magical ring and one finger later,  I find myself accidentally triggering the trap.

Now,  I accepted the gm ruling on this because I felt stupid for forgetting such a basic thing and it was my fault for forgetting.

My question is, as GM's,  should you remind your players about things that their characters should not have forgotten,  especially as obvious as a trap that they just discovered?

Comment: Is your question "how should you handle", or "should you remind" players who forget? These are *very* different questions.

Comment: I find that both those questions are linked... Handling it may involve reminding the players... Happy to make amendments to improve the post...